# Can I ask a recommendation question?

Tags: discussion

I want some advice on buying a juicer with certain specifications - ideally I'm looking for links to a few good ones.

Are you allowed to ask recommendation questions here, i.e. "What is a good juicer for ...?"

**Update**

Here is the question: *[What's an easy to use juicer that juices oranges as well as other fruit?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/whats-an-easy-to-use-juicer-that-juices-oranges-as-well-as-other-fruit)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, thank you for asking here on meta first - I know that the rules seem to be rather inconsistent between various Stack Exchanges.

The simple answer is **no**, however, most of the time, *that's not what you really want*.  Anybody can recommend their favourite products, but when all is said and done and the answers and votes are in, all you'd really have is a localized measure of popular opinion, which really doesn't get you any closer to buying the right product *for you*.

We **can** help you shop for equipment and other culinary items, but it's better for us *and* you if you phrase it as a request for *information*, not *opinions*.  Some good examples of "recommendation" type questions are:

- [What to look for when purchasing a blender?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4278/41)
- [What should I look for in a good, multi-purpose chef's knife?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/6158/41)

Both of the above examples are essentially asking *how* to shop, not *what* to get.  As you can see, the answers to these questions have far more lasting value than highly-localized and opinionated brand/model recommendations.

I also asked this one:

- [Are there significant differences between different brands/models of immersion blenders?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/10532/41)

which was a bit of a different tack, and I got a slightly different perspective in the answers.  I asked this question because after careful examination of the products out there (I actually *did* know what to look for, sort of), I really didn't see any notable differences between the products I was seeing in stores.  I got two answers, one which would probably be great help to other people who stumble upon the question, but the one that turned out to be most useful to me effectively said *"Yes, most of the consumer brands **are** the same, and if you really want to see where the differences are you need to start looking at restaurant equipment."*

I'd tend to recommend the last formulation of the question for people who *already* have done their homework regarding features and prices, and just aren't seeing enough variation to make a decision.

So please try to use one of the above question "templates" or something similar; it doesn't need to be rote copy-and-paste, but it's important to word it in such a way that it isn't encouraging people merely to offer up their unverified opinions.  You get less noise in your answers, we get less noise on the site - everybody wins.

Comment: thank you for your thank you! =:-) Always welcome. Having read your answer, I'm not sure what to do (because of my question - your answer was great). The question is: is there a (good) juicer for both oranges and other fruit? Maybe I could post it without mentioning "good"?

Comment: @Wikis: Think about the *results* you are trying to achieve; do you care about the consistency? The yield? The total capacity? The nutritional content? Do you care if you have to peel or seed the fruits first? I don't own a juicer myself, I'm getting all this from a 30-second Google search. If you don't know anything about juicers and want to know what types and features are available and which are important, then ask *that* question. Alternatively, if you know which features you want but can't find anything that fits, ask about *that*. Please *don't* ask for general recommendations, though.

Comment: alright, I'll give it a good. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what you should focus on:

> What *problem* are you trying to solve?

Don't ask us for a recommendation, tell us what your *specific* problem is and we'll give you advice about it. That may or may not include buying a product.

Beyond that, do read

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Comment: thanks. I think I've achieved that but let me know if not: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/whats-an-easy-to-use-juicer-that-juices-oranges-as-well-as-other-fruit